# How to get common values from 4 multidimensional arrays using array_intersect

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am stuck at this stage of my project.

i am trying to get common values from four multidimensional arrays using array_intersect. can anyone help me with this issue ?

here are all four array:

```
$arr=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array( 8168),array(8178),array( 8182),array( 8183));


$arr1=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array(8165),array(8166),array(8167),array( 8168));


$arr2=array(array(566),array(265),array(8134),array(655),array(8166),array(665),array( 8168),array(656),array( 989),array( 989));

$arr3=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array(8165),array(8166),array(8167),array( 8168));

$res= array_intersect($arr,$arr1,$arr2,$arr3); 

print_r($res);
```

Comment: hint: array map serialize array intersect array map unserialize

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing every element in its own, single value array?

Comment: It's wrong approach. `Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.`. So function would compare 'Array' values instead of real values.

Comment: @MarkM i am not storing any results as shown above... i have shown all arrays as i  got in my $wpdb->get_results() in wordpress.

Comment: @sectus. good point.. but how can i compare those values in my issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If subarray contain one element always you could chage that value using [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) and [current](http://php.net/current) function.

```
$arr=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array( 8168),array(8178),array( 8182),array( 8183));
$arr1=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array(8165),array(8166),array(8167),array( 8168));
$arr2=array(array(566),array(265),array(8134),array(655),array(8166),array(665),array( 8168),array(656),array( 989),array( 989));
$arr3=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array(8165),array(8166),array(8167),array( 8168));

$arr = array_map('current', $arr);   // getting first value of subarray
$arr1 = array_map('current', $arr1);
$arr2 = array_map('current', $arr2);
$arr3 = array_map('current', $arr3);
print_r($arr3);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 8159
//     [1] => 8140
//     [2] => 8134
//     [3] => 8165
//     [4] => 8166
//     [5] => 8167
//     [6] => 8168
// )

$res= array_intersect($arr,$arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
print_r($res);
// Array
// (
//    [2] => 8134
//    [3] => 8168
// )
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this

```
$arr=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array( 8168),array(8178),array( 8182),array( 8183));
$arr1=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array(8165),array(8166),array(8167),array( 8168));
$arr2=array(array(566),array(265),array(8134),array(655),array(8166),array(665),array( 8168),array(656),array( 989),array( 989));
$arr3=array(array(8159),array(8140),array(8134),array(8165),array(8166),array(8167),array( 8168));
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    $a1[] = $value[0];
}
foreach($arr1 as $value)
{
    $a2[] = $value[0];
}
foreach($arr2 as $value)
{
    $a3[] = $value[0];
}
foreach($arr3 as $value)
{
    $a4[] = $value[0];
}
$res= array_intersect($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4); 
print_r($res);
```